# Exact meaning of "application window will close on <date>": submission ok at <date> or only (<date>-1)?

Tags: job-search, applications, deadlines

A job ad says the following: "The application window will close on the 14th of January."

Does this mean on Friday the 14th applications can still be submitted until the end of the day or does it mean that from the 14th at 0:00 on applications will no longer be received (meaning they'd have to be submitted on the 13th)?

I know this might not be super well defined. Thanks for any comments!

Comment: It's clearly unclear exactly when the application window closes.  Rather than try to time it exactly, why don't you submit your application in advance of the closing date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'd be safest to presume that you need to have a submission by Jan 13 at 11:59 pm. If uploading to a web site, consider the factor of differing time zones.  DO NOT do your submission at the last minute.

Or you could call, and ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I contacted the company's HR and they responded that meant is "Jan 13 at 11:59 pm".

Answer (score 3):

The company has no obligation to even look at your application. So to be on the safe side, I'd make sure my application is in on the day before during business hours. If their office closes Thursday at 5pm, they might just throw away anything arriving later, unread. This may be unfair to anyone submitting their application later, but nothing you can do about that.